# Putting Joda Time Period and LocalDate into a Parcel?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm trying to make one of my classes parcellable, but while reading a Joda Time Period object as serializable, an NPE is thrown.

**Code:**

```
private Event(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readLong();
    this.scheduleId = in.readLong();
    this.entryId = in.readLong();
    this.time = (Period) in.readSerializable(); // NPE in this line.
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeLong(id);
    out.writeLong(scheduleId);
    out.writeLong(entryId);
    out.writeSerializable(time);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Event> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Event>() {
    public Event createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Event(in);
    }

    public Event[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Event[size];
    }
};
```

**Logcat:**

```
09-22 22:48:47.929  32708-32708/com.vibhinna.cubs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vibhinna.cubs, PID: 32708
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vibhinna.cubs/com.vibhinna.cubs.ui.EventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            .....
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:60)
            at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2210)
            at com.vibhinna.cubs.engine.Event.<init>(Event.java:110)
            at com.vibhinna.cubs.engine.Event.<init>(Event.java:10)
            at com.vibhinna.cubs.engine.Event$1.createFromParcel(Event.java:251)
            at com.vibhinna.cubs.engine.Event$1.createFromParcel(Event.java:249)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2013)
            ......
```

What causes this and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `time` object is null when it is written to the `Parcel` and you get when you are unmarshalling the object later. I can say it from the `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:60)` line, when the `Parcel` tries to initialize the `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Ensure that time object is not null when you write it to the parcel. 
[Alternatively](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object)), use `parcel.writeValue(time);` and `readValue()`, respectively, documentation says that it accepts `null` and `? implements Serializable` as object.

Comment: That NPE was due to some artifacts from a createTypedArray I had performed in the line before, sorry, I hadn't posted that code, regarding writing and reading the Period object, I just performed `time.toString()` which converts it into a ISO8601 format string, It can be converted back using `new Period(in.readstring())`, I think this would be the ,most efficient method.